# How to search for an object by class in the LDAP base?

Tags: ldap, pgp

I'm trying to search an LDAP for an object of a specific class, but it always returns

```
result: 32 No such object
```

Background:

I'm trying to access a PGP Universal server at keyserver.pgp.com which is a PGP server with LDAP access. It has an object of class pgpServerInfo that holds some informatione about how the PGP keys can be retrieved.

I am not well versed with LDAP, so my approach may be completely wrong.

This is what I tried:

```
ldapsearch -v -x -H ldap://keyserver.pgp.com "(objectclass=pgpServerInfo)"
```

I've also tried to add `-s base` and `-s one`, but no difference.

This works:

```
ldapsearch -v -x -b "cn=PGPServerInfo" -H ldap://keyserver.pgp.com "(objectClass=pgpServerInfo)"
```

But by doing so, I have to assume the object's name which I would like to avoid.

What's the correct query to find the object?

Comment: Does the "ldaps://" in your example that does not work, and the "ldap://" in your example that does work, have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't make a difference if it's ldap or ldaps. But thanks for pointing that out. I changed it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid assuming a base name you can try the following:
`ldapsearch -v -x -s base -H ldap://keyserver.pgp.com "(objectclass=*)" +`

Note the `+` in the search.  This will list "operational attributes".

This should provide you with a bunch of information including a number of "namingContexts".  You can then choose the namingContexts until you get which one you're looking for.

Comment: This helps! However, I don't understand what you mean when you say "you're still making some assumptions because you still have to choose the base from a list"? I'd go through the returned list of the namingContexts one by one checking the object class. So what assumptions?

Comment: Any of the namingContexts could have contained items with an objectClass of "pgpServerInfo".  In the case for this key server, the base you were looking for "cn=PGPServerInfo" happen to have a name that was very similar to the objectClass (pgpServerInfo) you wanted, but that didn't have to be the case.  Due to that, I felt that you were not eliminating all assumptions.  However, my comment about assumptions does not add much (if anything) to the answer, so I will edit the answer.  I will also add a bit more information about what makes the search I provided a bit different from what you tried.